# Creating a criteria search funtion in dataframe creates null error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've created a function that searches through a dataframe for multiple criteria using the df.loc method, and then pulls the dataframe from the subset that ensues.  This works just as I want.

However, if the df.loc doesn't match any rows (usually because the data didn't start in the year requested by the function), inevitably, I get an error.

My function looks like this:

```
#import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mm_df = pd.read_csv("mm_copy.csv", index_col=False, low_memory=False) # NB "index_col = False" is necessary because otherwise Python tries to use first column as index, \
                                                       #and throws everything out by one column

countries_df = pd.read_csv("countries.csv") 
south_america_df = countries_df.loc[countries_df.Continent == "South America"]
south_american_countries_list = south_america_df.Entity.tolist() # Creates complete list of South American countries, using local definitions

population_df = pd.read_csv("population.csv", low_memory=False)
population_df.set_index("Location")


def calculate_crude_maternal_mortality(year):
    
    # Establishes total WHO female population of South America
    who_female_pop_slice = population_df.loc[(population_df.Location == "South America") & (population_df.Time == year)]
    who_female_pop = who_female_pop_slice["TPopulationFemale1July"].values[0]*1000


    #Calc total South American Female population in relevant year
    south_american_female_pop_list = []
    south_american_mm_deaths_list = []


    mm_dict_for_year = {}

    for country in south_american_countries_list: # iterates through list of South American countries

        mm_dict_value_list = []

        if mm_df["Country_Name"].str.contains(country).any(): # checks country is in population dataframe
            mm_df_slice = mm_df.loc[(mm_df.Country_Name == country) & (mm_df.Year == year) & (mm_df.Sex == "Female") & (mm_df.Age_group_code=="Age_all")] # locates appropriate row which has country and year
            if mm_df_slice is not None:   #int(mm_df_slice.Number.values[0]) >= 0:
                country_mm_deaths = int(mm_df_slice.Number.values[0]) # finds cell with female population
                mm_dict_value_list.append(country_mm_deaths) # adds this population to the totals list
        else:
            mm_dict_value_list.append("No data")
        
        if population_df["Location"].str.contains(country).any(): # checks country is in population dataframe
            population_df_slice = population_df.loc[(population_df.Location == country) & (population_df.Time == year)] # locates appropriate row which has  country and year
            country_female_pop = int(population_df_slice["TPopulationFemale1July"].values[0] * 1000) # finds cell with female population, multiplies by 1000, and casts as int
            mm_dict_value_list.append(country_female_pop) # adds this population to the totals list
        else:
            mm_dict_value_list.append("No data")

        mm_dict_for_year[country] = mm_dict_value_list

    
    #print(mm_dict_for_year) #IMPORTANT TRACER

    # Create dictionary of actual mortalities and populations, country by country, for the requested year

    for country in mm_dict_for_year:
        if mm_dict_for_year[country][0] != "No data":
            if mm_dict_for_year[country][1] != "No data":
                south_american_mm_deaths_list.append(mm_dict_for_year[country][0])
                south_american_female_pop_list.append(mm_dict_for_year[country][1])

    data_coverage_percentage = round((sum(south_american_female_pop_list)/who_female_pop*100), 2)
    crude_maternal_mortality_rate = round((sum(south_american_mm_deaths_list)/sum(south_american_female_pop_list)*100000), 2)

    print("Data coverage = " + str(data_coverage_percentage * 100))

    if data_coverage_percentage < 80:
        print("Coverage below threshold of 80%")
    else:
        print(str(year) + ": Crude maternal mortality rate for all of South America was " + str(crude_maternal_mortality_rate) + " per 100000 females, and data coverage was " + str(data_coverage_percentage) + "%.")

 
    
calculate_crude_maternal_mortality(1993)
```

And the data csv file (a few sample rows) looks like this:

```
Region_Code,Region_Name,Country_Code,Country_Name,Year,Sex,Age_group_code,Age_Group,Number,Percentage_cause-specific_deaths_of_total_deaths,Age-standardized_death_rate_per_100k_standard_pop,Death_rate_per_100k_pop
CSA,Central and South America,PRY,Paraguay,2014,Female,Age70_74,[70-74],0.00000000,0.00000000,,0.00000000,
CSA,Central and South America,PRY,Paraguay,2014,Female,Age75_79,[75-79],0.00000000,0.00000000,,0.00000000,
CSA,Central and South America,PRY,Paraguay,2014,Female,Age80_84,[80-84],0.00000000,0.00000000,,0.00000000,
CSA,Central and South America,PRY,Paraguay,2014,Female,Age85_over,[85+],0.00000000,0.00000000,,0.00000000,
CSA,Central and South America,PRY,Paraguay,2014,Female,Age_unknown,[Unknown],0.00000000,0.00000000,,,
CSA,Central and South America,PER,Peru,1995,All,Age_all,[All],301.00000000,0.32901569,1.27784199,1.23872595,
CSA,Central and South America,PER,Peru,1995,All,Age00,[0],0.00000000,0.00000000,,0.00000000,
CSA,Central and South America,PER,Peru,1995,All,Age01_04,[1-4],0.00000000,0.00000000,,0.00000000,
CSA,Central and South America,PER,Peru,1995,All,Age05_09,[5-9],0.00000000,0.00000000,,0.00000000,
CSA,Central and South America,PER,Peru,1995,All,Age10_14,[10-14],2.00000000,0.17346054,,0.07080373,
CSA,Central and South America,PER,Peru,1995,All,Age15_19,[15-19],32.00000000,1.63432074,,1.24696102,
CSA,Central and South America,PER,Peru,1995,All,Age20_24,[20-24],63.00000000,2.43055556,,2.72412878,
CSA,Central and South America,PER,Peru,1995,All,Age25_29,[25-29],52.00000000,2.07750699,,2.57749333,
```

So in my example here, when my iterating loop looks up 1993, for example, there is no data for 1993, so the df.loc is empty, and it throws the error code.

Any ideas on how to avoid this?  I wondered about something along the lines of searching for the min() in the year column, and if the searched for year is < than this, returning "No data", but I can't get this to work, particularly with multiple criteria (Sex = female and Year = 1993).

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Could you provide countries.csv sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be lines that contain the following:

```py
if mm_df_slice is not None:
```

It will never be None, as .loc returns a subset of a DataFrame, which can be empty, but not null.

Instead of using the logic:

```py
if df.str.contains(x):
    if subset is not None:
        ...
```

You will be better using the "pythonic" way:

```py
# Get the dataframe, without checking the contains
mm_df_slice = mm_df.loc[(mm_df.Country_Name == country) & (mm_df.Year == year) & (mm_df.Sex == "Female") & (mm_df.Age_group_code=="Age_all")]
# And then, check if results are empty
if not mm_df_slice.empty:
    # Calculate stuff
else:
    mm_dict_value_list.append('No data')
```